# .htaccess wildcard subdomain redirect with wildcard path 404 not found

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect wildcard subdomains with a wildcard path and it seems to be working, however when the url has any path a 404 error is returned.

For example https://test.mydomain.com/ will redirect with no issues to https://new.mydomain.com/ while https://test.mydomain.com/test will return a 404 error not found. I need https://test.mydomain.com/test to redirect to https://new.mydomain.com/test

My current .htaccess file is as follows

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^\*\.mydomain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.\*\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/new\.mydomain\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue might be that the redirect is being redirected, i.e. when `test` is redirected to `new`, that is being redirected again to `new` because of the `*` in the condition. Try editing as follows to not apply it to new.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %1 !^new$
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it didn't seem to work either. After messing around with it I was able to get this to work by adding it to the end. I'm not 100% sure if this is the best way to do it but it works for me so I guess I'll leave it at that.
RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ https://mydomaincom/.$1

Comment: See edit above, I think you might be getting into a redirect loop

Comment: I tried your edit. Also tried redirecting to the root domain which ultimately redirects to a new subdomain and got the same issue. The only thing I've gotten to work so far is RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)$ mydomaincom/.$1

Comment: I marked your answer as best answer for your time. Appreciate your help.